# JavaScript Redirect depending on the Domain (for Blogger website)

Tags: javascript, redirect, blogger

I have a blogspot blog (Blogger). And have just noticed that my posts are being scraped (illegally copied) onto another site by some low-life.

I have 2 options:

1. Just ignore it
2. Try to trick them

I would like to put a script on my blog posts that look for the domain name of my blog, and if it is not correct, to redirect the viewer to my blog.
Is this possible? Will it work?

I am hoping that the scrape method being used is just a copy-paste method, and would like to redirect anyone who visits the offending site back to me (the original content creator).

I know that they could just remove the script, but I would still like to know if it can be done. I would like to see if it works.

Comment: How is this going to work, if the content of the text is copied to another domain..? how exactly will this script execute from your website if user is on another one?

Comment: The post below is a good answer to your query, but your second part about 'will it work' the answer is unlikely. Most likely the scraping script or manual copier is using the url of the page, using a google href, etc. and not copying the link within your blog which brought them to the article.

Comment: I am hoping that they are just copying the HTML from my post without looking at the contents of the HTML. I am hoping that I can get them to run a script that will redirect them back to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (window.location.href !== "YOURSITE") window.location.href = "YOURSITE";
```

Should work fine **if they copy the entire HTML**

If they just copy the text, this won't work at all.

Getting your articles copied sucks, I hope you'll be able to resolve it.

Comment: This does not help to address the issue described, it's impossible to achieve what the OP wants. You can't just execute a script from his website while browsing another site.

Comment: The OP is hoping that the evil-doers are copying the source HTML, script tags and all. It seems unlikely.

Comment: @ivo Oh I'm sure they aren't, I'm just answering what OP had asked. I'll edit in a disclaimer for future readers.

Comment: @ScottC Assuming they're copying the entire HTML, yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: I am hoping that they are copying the entire HTML. It seems like they are. But I should find out soon. Thank you for your help

Comment: Checking for my blog URL would be difficult due to regional extensions, so how can I check and accept my blog site URL without the regional extensions.  For example:  I am happy enough if the location.href starts with "http//myblog.blogspot...."

Comment: Thank you. I think I could possibly do it this way also: if(window.location.href.includes("myblog.blogspot"))

Comment: if (window.location.href.indexOf("myblog.blogspot") < 0) window.location.href = "YOURSITE";